# Magento 2: Update payment methods on change billing address from existing billing options

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, billing-address

How to update payment methods on change billing address from existing billing options Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.updateAddresses()` function
in

```
updateAddress: function () {
            var addressData, newBillingAddress;

            if (this.selectedAddress() && !this.isAddressFormVisible()) {
                selectBillingAddress(this.selectedAddress());
                checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(this.selectedAddress().getKey());
                this.updateAddresses();
            } else {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger(this.dataScopePrefix + '.data.validate');

                if (this.source.get(this.dataScopePrefix + '.custom_attributes')) {
                    this.source.trigger(this.dataScopePrefix + '.custom_attributes.data.validate');
                }

                if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    addressData = this.source.get(this.dataScopePrefix);

                    if (customer.isLoggedIn() && !this.customerHasAddresses) { //eslint-disable-line max-depth
                        this.saveInAddressBook(1);
                    }
                    addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook() ? 1 : 0;
                    newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(addressData);

                    // New address must be selected as a billing address
                    selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);
                    checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(newBillingAddress.getKey());
                    checkoutData.setNewCustomerBillingAddress(addressData);
                }
            }
```

In `view/billing-address.js` file to update address on change billing address.